# Where from I get Ribhu Gita?

Tags: shiva-purana

Can You Tell me where from I get the ***Ribhu Gita*** in Sanskrit-Hindi Translation/Transliteration. I searched everywhere in markets and also on Internet.Help me if you know This rarest book?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [**Ribhu Gita**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shivarahasya_Purana#Ribhu_Gita) is  the 6th part  of the Hinduism scripture called  as **Shivarahasya Purana** . This is one of the  Upapuranas  concerning to Shaiva tradition . Here in this Purana we find  teachings of Lord Siva  to His devotee RIBHU.
The content of Ribhu Gita is  been described as  related to advaita, monist or nondual philosophy. Ribhu Gita is a dialogue between Sage Ribhu and Sage Nidagha about the Atman and Brahman.

As you are required here is [**English Downloadable PDF**](https://spiritual-minds.com/easternrelgions/Gita/RibhuGita/The-Ribhu-Gita-ppt.pdf)  Of Ribhu Gita by By Dr Pradeep Apte

---

And here are the [**Sanskrit shlokas of the Ribhu Gita.**](https://sanskritdocuments.org/sites/ribhugita/RGChap01.html)

---

If you are interested in listning to it here is [**Ribhu Gita in MP3 format**](https://www.sriramanamaharshi.org/resource_centre/audio/sri-ribhu-gitai/) where we can listen or download chapter files.